# there is no edit option on certain views of drupal site

Tags: views, blocks

There are certain blocks/views in drupal site where edit option is not coming and i am unable to figure out how to change them.

Comment: there a option for do this in views,in advanced part set"hide contextual links" to NO

Comment: There are contextual links to edit the block, edit the view, and also in some cases to edit the content that is in the view results. Which edit link are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

There is a "Hide contextual links" setting in views to turn contextual links on and off.

Set "Hide contextual links" to "No" as per this screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set the "Format" -> "Show" Option to "Content" (or even "Display Suite"). The contextual links will not appear if you display fields only.